# How to make the tab container take up 100% of the height

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm working with the TabContainer control from the Ajax toolkit and even though I set the width and height to 100% it doesn't seem to work.

```
<form ..>        
<asp:ScriptManager ../>
<cc1:TabContainer style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding-top:10px" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" >
        <cc1:TabPanel ../>
        <cc1:TabPanel ../>
</cc1:TabContainer>
</form>
```

The control renders with the width as 100% but the height seems to be fixed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a way to do this so I ended up just using jQuery to do it. I added a function that happens when the page is loaded that resizes the the tab container to fill the remaining space.